# swift - embedded SWRevealViewController to you application

Tags: swift, xcode6, swrevealviewcontroller

I intergrade SWRevealViewController to my project

my project flow is 
              viewcontroller ---> SWRevealViewController -->menu
                                                          --> nav-->front view

the segue method from my initial view controller to SWRevealViewController is model

my problem is when my I open toggle in front view for first time only

it give me empty menu(table view)

my front view code

```
@IBOutlet weak var open: UIBarButtonItem!
    @IBOutlet weak var result: UILabel!

    @IBAction func showmore(sender: AnyObject) {
        performSegueWithIdentifier("resdes", sender: sender)
    }



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


       var res =  Uti.get_result()
        result.text = res.description

        open.target = self.revealViewController()
        open.action = Selector("revealToggle:")
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
```

my rear code

```
class slidemenuVC : UITableViewController{

    var menuItems = [String]()

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        menuItems = ["Result","About us","References","Rest Test"]
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return menuItems.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(menuItems[indexPath.row], forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

        cell.textLabel?.text = menuItems[indexPath.row]
        return cell

    }


}
```

[image]

Second problem :

when I press at first menu item , navigation disappear

[image]

it should be like this have toggle

Comment: What do you have on the rear viewcontroller? if you're having troubles there, then we need to see the code

Comment: I update my answer , thank you for your interested

Comment: Have you put a breakpoint on method to get the cell to see if it's executed?

Comment: I fix first problem , viewDidAppear is wrong it should be viewDidLoad

Answer (score 0):

```
var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(menuItems[indexPath.row], forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
```

is wrong. You need your identifier has to be the actual cell id in your uitableviewcell